# How to get file name which is uploaded in the attachment using php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a form in which I am submitting email and a attachment in database. The form is submitting but I can not get the name of the file in database. How can I get the name of the file which I have uploaded.

here is my code

```
$ImageSavefolder = "dashboard/document/"; //folder name where image saves
$uploadfile = $ImageSavefolder . basename($_FILES['uploadDoc']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadDoc"]["tmp_name"] , $uploadfile);

$query1 = "INSERT into docs (docs_name, userid, appointmentid) VALUES('$uploadfile', '$userid', '$appointid')";
$inserted1 = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query1);

if($inserted1 == 1 ){
    $json = array(
                    "status" => '200',
                    "data" => array("success" => "Doc uploaded successfully.")
                );

} else {
    $json = array(
                "status" => '400',
                "data" => array("error" => "File too large. File must be less than 2MB.")
            );
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code? it's a mess now.

Comment: The original file name is contained in `$_FILES['uploadDoc']['name']` as you already used in your code. Just check the [php file handling chapter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more infos.

Comment: sorry for the mess and i am uploading the file from android app and it is not getting the name of file $_FILES['uploadDoc']['name']

Answer (score 0):

It's all here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
Just read first entry (`$_FILES['userfile']['name']`).